# Is there a way so I can use GazeCloudAPI offline?

Tags: api, eye-tracking

Is there a way so I can use [GazeCloudAPI](https://gazerecorder.com/gazecloudapi/) offline?
For example, load the webpage and then use it without an internet connection?

Thanks a lot